# High Concurrency Write in database

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, locking, ejb

In my web-service i have a user table which contains column called "HITS",now as a user in this user class/table consumes the web-service,"HITS" count is incremented by 1.which involves write operation and hence comes in optimistic/pessimistic locks.

Issue am facing is high concurrency scenario,in which 100 hits come simultaneously for same user.

Can anyone suggest me a strategy to avoid delays caused by locking a user row to update "HITS" when web-service is used simultaneously from same user's account ?

OR

you can also suggest a way to update some variable which i can monitor after every 12 hours,to generate the "HITS" value,by summing up the variable(s) or something like that ?

Am using hibernate and EJB stateless session bean.

Comment: Does the database support commit-rollback?

Comment: yes,database support commit & rollback.Why you asked that?

Comment: Then you could make it an atomic operation.  But the idea of just stuffing them in and counting them later is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just insert one record for every hit into table `all_hits`...

then on some schedule - select from that table, and insert into `hits_summary` table, and delete the originals.